# Easy way to deal with free in an array

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

When I have a function that gets a pointer `int *vector` with a couple `int` values. I want to delete element number `n`. So I will use `free()` on that element. The problem I have now that there is a "hole" in my array of int values. Is there an easy way that I dont have this problem or do I really have to make a new int pinter and reorder my vector?

Comment: `vector[n]` is an `int`... you can't `free()` that.

Comment: You can create a array of structure to make a fake int array or chain list.

Comment: `free()` doesn't do or work the way you think

Comment: You can't use `free` to do that. `free` is used to free up dynamic memory that you've allocated with `malloc` or one of the variants of `malloc`. If you want an ordered list of items that you can easily remove or add to and not leave holes, a suitable structure is probably a linked list, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a function of this form:

```
void delete_element(int *vector, size_t index) {
    // ...
}
```

The actual argument corresponding to `vector` is expected to be a pointer to a series of one or more (implied: `index + 1` or more) contiguous `int`s.  This could be part or all of an ordinary `int` array, or it could be a dynamically allocated block.  If the former, then you cannot free any part of the space at all.  If the latter, then you can free or reallocate the *whole* space, but not just the part associated with one element.

To avoid the deletion leaving a hole in your array, you need to move the later elements down, and to do that, you need to know how many elements there are in total.  Therefore, you need a more informative function signature, perhaps something like this:

```
void delete_element(int *vector, size_t *size, size_t index) {
    // ...
}
```

The actual deletion might involve simply using `memmove()` to move the later elements (overwriting the one to be deleted), and then decrementing the size.  With respect to the latter, note that I suggest passing a pointer to the vector size, so that the function can modify the caller's copy.

If you want also to shrink the allocation then you need to do a bit more work (involving calling `realloc()`, and communicating the revised value of `vector` back to the caller), but note that in that case your function will not work on ordinary arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to free() part of a block returned by malloc().  If you want to delete record[n], you need to copy record[n+1]...record[last] into the array.

If you really need to free() each element, you must first malloc() each element.